# CSS Transition not working correctly

Tags: html, css

I have a progress bar from code that I got off a website, now what I'm trying to do is add a transition whenever the percent changes, so that then it does not simply "snap" to the position, rather a ease, but for some reason it won't work

Heres the mark up

```
<div class="meter">
<span style="width: 25%"></span>
</div>
```

And the CSS

```
 .meter { 
height: 20px;  /* Can be anything */
position: relative;
background: #555;
-moz-border-radius: 25px;
-webkit-border-radius: 25px;
border-radius: 25px;
padding: 10px;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
-moz-box-shadow   : inset 0 -1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
box-shadow        : inset 0 -1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
}
.meter > span {
display: block;
height: 100%;

   -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 8px;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
       -moz-border-radius-topright: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 8px;
           border-top-right-radius: 8px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 20px;
 -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
        -moz-border-radius-topleft: 20px;
     -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 20px;
            border-top-left-radius: 20px;
         border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
background-color: rgb(43,194,83);
background-image: -webkit-gradient(
  linear,
  left bottom,
  left top,
  color-stop(0, rgb(43,194,83)),
  color-stop(1, rgb(84,240,84))
 );
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(
  center bottom,
  rgb(43,194,83) 37%,
  rgb(84,240,84) 69%
 );
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(
  center bottom,
  rgb(43,194,83) 37%,
  rgb(84,240,84) 69%
 );
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(
  center bottom,
  rgb(43,194,83) 37%,
  rgb(84,240,84) 69%
 );
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(
  center bottom,
  rgb(43,194,83) 37%,
  rgb(84,240,84) 69%
 );
-webkit-box-shadow: 
  inset 0 2px 9px  rgba(255,255,255,0.3),
  inset 0 -2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
-moz-box-shadow: 
  inset 0 2px 9px  rgba(255,255,255,0.3),
  inset 0 -2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
```

}

And here's the code I put into `.meter > span`

```
   transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
```

And [here's](http://jsbin.com/yeloguho/1/edit) a jsbin link. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You using `opacity` as transition but **you dont use** opacity in your css.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the `width` to be transitioned, use `transition: width` (and then the time, function, etc.)

`transition` will transition whatever property you tell it to, or you can use the keyword `all` to transition all properties - but use with care! Chrome doesn't do too well with this when zooming...

Aside: Your border radius code could be a lot simpler:

```
border-radius: 8px 8px 20px 20px;
```

Prefixes haven't been needed in a *long* time.

Comment: Oh... also, the width change needs to happen within the page, not by you editing the page XD

Comment: I don't understand. The width is a variable, so it'll change. The variable is through javascript. So how would I make this work correctly then?

Comment: Look at the demo I gave you.

Comment: I don't think *you* understand what you're trying to do. The width is set when the page starts. JavaScript then changes it, and *that* is when the transition happens. In JsBin, when you change the HTML, it counts as the page starting again.

Comment: Let me be more descriptive. I'm making this as a project. You add input fields in the HTML and then there is a progress bar that changes as you complete the form. Remove a field and it moves back down. So I use `form.getElementsByTagName('input').length` to get how many input there are, then divide it by `100` giving me a percent, and each input completed equals that percent. That's what I'm trying to do. Do you understand now?

Comment: @user3624247 and thats what you will do with `document.querySelector(".meter > span").style.width = percent+"%";`

Comment: Like this form http://git.aaronlumsden.com/progression/ But instead of simply clicking on it, and get the percent, the input must be filled

Comment: I added another form and filled it, yet it still doesn't work. @t.niese